# Problems when building Uno Platform project from command line

Tags: uno-platform

I have created a class library based on netstandard 2.0 and successfully included it in a droid app. Everything works fine when debugging from Visual Studio. I tried build this from the command line with `dotnet`  and here's where the strange things happen. Build goes fine but when running `dotnet pack` it says build failed with 0 errors and 0 warnings:

```
   1:5>UnoResourcesGeneration:
         Generating resources for platform :
       Done executing task "ResourcesGenerationTask_v331aaa6f42492821058b51435a68065fe542d4fe" -- FAILED.
   1:5>Done Building Project "....csproj" (_GetFrameworkAssemblyReferences target(s)) -- FAILED.
     1>Done executing task "MSBuild" -- FAILED.
     1>Done building target "_WalkEachTargetPerFramework" in project "....csproj" -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "....csproj" (pack target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

This is run with .NET 5 and I tried to compile this with .NET Core 2 which in addition produces the following message:

```
      "....csproj" (pack target) (1) ->
       (_UnoSourceGenerator target) ->
         ...\.nuget\packages\uno.sourcegenerationtasks\3.0.0\build\netstandard1.0\Uno.SourceGenerationTasks.targets(134,2): error MSB4062: The "Uno.SourceGeneratorTasks.SourceGenerationTask_v7422c41155a89db34b1e3241cd4c4761f2cabf5f" task could not be loaded from the assembly ...\.nuget\packages\uno.sourcegenerationtasks\3.0.0\build\netstandard1.0\..\Dev15.0\netcoreapp3.1\Uno.SourceGeneratorTasks.v7422c41155a89db34b1e3241cd4c4761f2cabf5f.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [....csproj]
```

(Paths removed)

Can anyone spot what is going on there? Works fine from Visual Studio but I need to be able to build this from the command line to set up a build on GitHub Actions.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 2 is a not supported target for building Uno platform apps. You will need to upgrade to at least .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: .NET Core 2 was just something I was trying out to see if that worked. It produced an error message that .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 didn't do. But it doesn't work with 3.1/5 either.

Comment: In this case, you may be doing something that we've missed. Could you open an issue in Uno with a sample code of what you're trying to do, and post the msbuild.binlog file there as well? https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-builds-troubleshooting.html#generating-msbuild-binary-log-files

Comment: I found out that the build error happens as soon as I reference `Uno.UI` from a class library targeting `netstandard2.0`. In my example, I have references like this: `Example.Droid > CustomLib > Uno.UI`. I'm not sure if referencing `Uno.UI` from a class library is supported? If so, I'll go ahead and create an issue.

Comment: Got it. Yes it is, but it needs a specific configuration. If you want to build a cross-targeted library, use the `Cross-Platform Library (Uno Platform)` template provided by the Visual Studio extension.

Comment: Changing to a Cross-Platform Library definitely helped. Not I see a real build error when building with `dotnet` saying that it is not supported (stated in the documentation as well). I can pack from within Visual Studio, so I just need to figure out how to replicate this from the command-line. Thank you very much for your help on this one. Feel free to recap in an answer if you'd like and I'll mark it as answered 